# Why does the "Hello" inside the string array have a size 4?

Tags: c, string, pointers, sizeof

The code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

 char *a[10] = {"hi", "Hello", "how"};
 printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));

 printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", a[0],a[1],a[2]);
 printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", sizeof(a[0]),sizeof(a[1]),sizeof(a[2]));

 printf("%d", sizeof("Hello"));
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
40
hi
Hello
how
4
4
4
6
```

I have no idea why this is happening and I also looked up the reference for `sizeof` on [cppreference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.cppreference.com%2Fw%2Fcpp%2Flanguage%2Fsizeof&ei=quNpVcuRD8XYywPco4HACg&usg=AFQjCNFIkeF3TsSJj4Fnk-t3ieWhgWd6qw&sig2=RUY-TvKv5ZhgLvqbNepJXw&bvm=bv.94455598,d.bGQ). Still have no clue why it is returning 4 for "Hello" when it should need 6 to store it.

Comment: So why you're not bothered how it returns 4 for "hi" and "how"?

Comment: OT: Use %zu instead of %d as sizeof returns a value of type size_t.

Answer (score 8):

It actually print the size of pointer not the string content itself. Look all of the size is printed as 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is an array of `char*`, so `sizeof(a[1])` is the size of a `char*`, which is 4 on your platform.

`sizeof("Hello")` is the size of a `char[6]`, which is, by definition, `6`. The reason for the latter is that `"Hello"` is a string literal whose type is length 6 array `char`, containing

```
{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}
```

Answer (score 3):

"Inside the string array" there are elements of type `char *` that is it is an array of pointers to chararcters because you defined it like

```
char *a[10] = {"hi", "Hello", "how"};
^^^^^^
```

When elements of such an array are initialized by string literals (that have types of character arrays) then they (string literals) are converted to pointers to their first elements. So array `a` is an array of pointers (the first three elements of the array) to first characters of the string literals. All other elements are zero-initialized.

Thus `sizeof( a[1] )` is equal to `sizeof( char * )` and in the environment where the prograam was run it is equal to 4

If you would define the array the following way

```
char a[][10] = {"hi", "Hello", "how"};
```

then in this case `sizeof( a[1] )` would be equal to 10 because in this case you explicitly specified that each element of the array has type `char[10]`

However if you would apply function `strlen` to `a[1]` you would get that `strlen( a[1] )` is equal to 5 (the terminating zero of the string literal is not counted).

As for the string literal "Hello" then in C it has type `char[6]` and sizeof( "Hello" ) is evidently equal to 6.

So if you have for example

```
char *s = "Hello";
```

then

```
sizeof( s ) is equal to 4;
sizeof( "Hello" ) is equal to 6;
and at last strlen( s ) is equal to strlen( "Hello" ) and equal to 5.
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is not a function, it is an operator which produces the size of the given *type*.

In your case, `a[0]` is of type `char *`, which, in your system, occupies 4 bytes of memory. So, it is producing `4`.

OTOH, while you use `sizeof("Hello")`, the *string* `"Hello"` here is of type `char[6]` (including null-terminator), so, it prints `6`.